# A Vector Question on a Cube (3D Problem)

Tags: geometry

As shown in the following figure, $E$ is the mid point of $AD$; $F$ is the mid point of $AB$.

Let $\theta$ be the angle formed by straight line $BC_1$ and plane $EFB_1 D_1$. Find $cos\theta$.

I find this vector application problem difficult. It is because I am not sure how the $\theta$ is formed. I do not know it should be obtuse or acute. Thanks in advance for help.

[image]

Comment: I think it's an acute angle. But it doesn't matter. You just get the cosine from a dot product, regardless.

Comment: @bubba Actually, it is quite difficult to find the normal vector of the plane $EFB_1D_1$. Would you please teach me how to do it?

Comment: Get two vectors lying in that plane, and compute their cross product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $A$ is on the origin and position vector of $B$ is $\hat{i}$, similarly $A_1$ on $\hat{j}$ and $D$ on $\hat{k}$. Every other point's position vector can now be defined in terms of these $3$. What you need now is the plane containing $E,F,B_1,D_1$. Or rather, just the normal vector of that plane. Since you have $4$, points, you can get $3$ vectors from them, and computing the cross product of any $2$ of them , you've got your normal vector $N$.

$$N=FB_1 \times FE$$

Now that you have your normal vector $N$ and the vector $BC_1$, to compute the angle between them, just do 
$$\theta=\arcsin{\frac{N \cdot BC_1}{|N| \cdot |BC_1|}} $$

Comment: Thank you very much. I got what you mean. Your explanation helps me a lot^^.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If the answer helped you, please accept the answer by clicking on the check box next to it.

Comment: Yes, I have done it. Thanks again=).